# What does "feed" mean in the phrase "line feed"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In computer science or printers/typewriters, there is a concept called "line feed" (abbrev. LF). What does the word "feed" mean here?

Comment: I found a relative explaination from wikipedia: The line feed indicated that one line of paper should feed out of the printer thus instructed the printer to advance the paper one line

Comment: I believe the term originally comes from [teletypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter#Control_characters), though it might be older. BTW, it's best to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line feed originally meant to advance paper in a printer by one line.  It's analogous to a carriage return on a typewriter, though I'm not sure if the term "line feed" was ever used for typewriters when they were the primary tool for producing print.  It now also means to move a cursor forward one line on a computer screen.

The original meaning for **line feed**, moving paper forward by a single increment, gives us the sense of the word feed that it uses.  Just as we might feed a draft horse to keep it working, we are feeding the machine paper one line at a time so that it can continue working.  This corresponds with one of the common verb forms of feed:

> **feed** (v.) supply (a machine) with material, power, or other things necessary for its operation.

Feed, verb form definition 2 from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=feed%20definition&oq=feed%20definition&gs_l=serp.3..0i67j0l5j0i22i30l4.2029.3342.0.3534.11.6.0.5.5.1.168.545.5j1.6.0.msedr...0...1c.1.60.serp..1.10.393.j_c1sZ2VOAc).

Comment: Please don't confuse line feed and carriage return. "Normally" they would go hand in hand (think old-fashioned typewriters where you'd move the lever), but they are two independent concepts: LF moves the paper forward, CR changes the position of the next letter to the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Stephie - Excellent point. I suppose the analogy might have been more accurate had it read: "It's analogous to an *extra* carriage return..."

Comment: @Stephie And there's newline as well...  That's why I said it was analogous rather than equivalent, nice clarification though.  :-)

Comment: On the sorts of typewriters I learned on the carriage return was usually set to do a line feed (but you could flick lever and get just a CR). Obviously a line feed was easy on its own. Computer printers could separately do LF and CR and there are two separate ASCII codes for them.

Answer (score 1):

Line feed in the context of computer science has a slightly different meaning. When you press `Enter` in a text document, it is represented as a line feed `LF` and `CR` carriage return characters on Windows, or a sigle `LF` character on other operating systems such as Linux or Mac. These are special characters, usually not shown by default in most of the visual editors.